# "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query in postgresql, what i expected was a table with two columns. one called counter and the other called forn_primario.
But instead i get this error: "column "forn_primario" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

```
Select MAX(contador) as counter, forn_primario
From(
Select COUNT(DISTINCT categoria) as contador, forn_primario
From produto
Group by forn_primario)t
```

Also after this query

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT categoria) as contador, forn_primario
From produto
Group by forn_primario
```

I get this table

```
 contador | forn_primario 
----------+---------------
        1 | 103246782
       17 | 113056729
        2 | 120456781
        3 | 123456719
        1 | 133956139
        2 | 143856248
        2 | 153756357
        1 | 163656466
        2 | 173516575
        1 | 183426684
        1 | 193336793
```

After the main query i'm should have this table:

```
  counter | forn_primario 
----------+---------------
       17 | 113056729
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT categoria) as contador, forn_primario
From produto
Group by forn_primario
Order by contador DESC
Limit 1;
```

Comment: what if two forn_primario having same count . need to use dense_rank()

Comment: that worked but only in this case, because if i have more than 1 forn_prim with the same count it wont work

Comment: @TiagoTaveira . . . In that case, you can solve the problem with `rank()`/`dense_rank()`.  I didn't mention this because an aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.

Answer (score -1):

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(categoria)) as Contador, forn_primario FROM produto GROUP BY forn_primario ORDER BY Contador DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It wont work if there is more than one forn_primario with the same counter